# Usage of import('something') vs. import from 'something'

Tags: javascript

I came across the following from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import):

```
var promise = import("module-name");
```

Is this deprecated, or when would that ever be used? I'm only familiar with the syntax of:

```
import promise from 'module-name';
```

Comment: 100krep and you can't even skim the rest of the page? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a static import:

```
import module from "module-name";
```

It's **statically** resolved, before any code is executed.

This is a **dynamic** import:

```
const promise = import("module-name");
```

The reason why it's named `promise` is because `import(...)` returns a promise that resolves to the imported module (errors if module not found).

So you can use it like this:

```
import("my-mod").then((myMod) => {
    myMod.func();
});
```

Or the more preferred async/await syntax:

```
const myMod = await import("my-mod");

myMod.func();
```

Dynamic imports are executed and resolved at runtime which is why you must wait for it to complete. They're commonly used for code-splitting, lazy loading, or importing modules when needed (plugins could be an example).